# Difficulties with understanding read.csv code

Tags: r

I'm improving my R-skills rebuilding some of the amazing stuff they do on r-bloggers. Right now im trying to reproduce this:
http://wiekvoet.blogspot.nl/2015/06/deaths-in-netherlands-by-cause-and-age.html. The relevant dataset for this excersize could be found here:

http://statline.cbs.nl/Statweb/publication/?VW=D&DM=SLNL&PA=7052_95&D1=0-1%2c7%2c30-31%2c34%2c38%2c42%2c49%2c56%2c62-63%2c66%2c69-71%2c75%2c79%2c92&D2=0&D3=0&D4=0%2c10%2c20%2c30%2c40%2c50%2c60%2c63-64&HD=150710-0924&HDR=G1%2cG2%2cG3&STB=T

If I'm diving into the code (to be found at the bottom of the first link) and am running into this piece of code:

```
 r1 <- read.csv(sep=';',header=FALSE,
    col.names=c('Causes','Causes2','Age','year','aantal','count'),
    na.strings='-',text=txtlines[3:length(txtlines)]) %>%
select(.,-aantal,-Causes2)
```

Could anybody help me seperating the steps that are taken here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation of what each line in the call to `read.csv()` is doing from your example.  Note that the assignment of the last parameter `text` is complicated and is dependent on the script from the link you gave above.  From a high level, he is first reading in all lines from the file `"Overledenen__doodsoo_170615161506.csv"` which contain the string `"Centraal"`, using only the third to final lines from that filtered set.  There is an additional step applied to these lines as well.

```
r1 <- read.csv( # columns separate by semi-colon
               sep=';',
                # first row is data (i.e. is NOT a header)
               header=FALSE,
                # names of the six columns
               col.names=c('Causes','Causes2','Age','year','aantal','count'),
                # treat hyphen as NA
               na.strings='-',
                # read from third line to final line of the original input
                # Overledenen__doodsoo_170615161506.csv, after some
                # filtering has been applied
               text=txtlines[3:length(txtlines)]) %>% select(.,-aantal,-Causes2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The read.csv, read the csv file, separating column with the separator ";"
so that an input like this a;b;c will be separated in: first column=a, second=b, third=c

header=FALSE -> It specifies no header in the original file was given.

col.names assigns the listed names to your columns in r

na.strings='-' substitutes NA values with '-'

text=txtlines[3:length(txtlines)]) read the lines from position 3 till the end.

%>% select(.,-aantal,-Causes2) filter the data frame